# Populating new pandas column values from different dataframe that match a column value and column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Apologies for weird phrasing, wasn't sure how to even convey the issue but hopefully the example will. I have two dataframes and want to populate a new column in df1 with values from df2 by matching them based on values in two df1 columns. The problem is that in df2 one of these values is not in the columns but rather is the column name.

```
df1

NAME YEAR

Anna 2002
Mary 2001
Paul 2000
Paul 2001
Mary 2002
Anna 2001
Anna 2000
Mary 2000
Paul 2002


df2

NAME 2000 2001 2002

Anna 5    4    3
Mary 3    2    5
Paul 2    3    4


expected result:

df1

NAME YEAR SCORE

Anna 2002 3
Mary 2001 2
Paul 2000 2
Paul 2001 3
Mary 2002 5
Anna 2001 4
Anna 2000 5
Mary 2000 3
Paul 2002 4
```

I can merge the two dataframes on NAME but that does not solve my issue since I would just add the three columns. I was wondering if this would require some for loops iterating through columns but I'm a beginner and am not sure if I'm not overcomplicating things (and creating a very long process). Even just a hint at where to look in the documentation would be super helpful!

Comment: Use `pd.melt` to solve this

Answer (score 1):

Try `pd.melt`:

```
pd.melt(df2, id_vars=['NAME'], value_vars=['2000', '2001', '2002'])
```

This will give:

```
   NAME variable  value
0  Anna     2000      5
1  Mary     2000      3
2  Paul     2000      2
3  Anna     2001      4
4  Mary     2001      2
5  Paul     2001      3
6  Anna     2002      3
7  Mary     2002      5
8  Paul     2002      4
```

Now you can merge

You can also rename column names:

```
df2.rename(columns={'variable':'YEAR', 'value':'SCORE'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative, use `.set_index()`/`.stack()`:

```py
print(
    df2.set_index("NAME")
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={0: "SCORE", "level_1": "YEAR"})
)
```

Prints:

```
   NAME  YEAR  SCORE
0  Anna  2000      5
1  Anna  2001      4
2  Anna  2002      3
3  Mary  2000      3
4  Mary  2001      2
5  Mary  2002      5
6  Paul  2000      2
7  Paul  2001      3
8  Paul  2002      4
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)¹ to "unpivot" multiple columns of data (e.g., `YEAR`) using the `NAME` column as the *identifier variable*

You don't need to use loops – `pandas` has built-in vectorized methods which are more optimally efficient. Also, it doesn't seem that your `df1` is needed for arriving at your desired result as given.

<sub>¹ ***Note:** Identical to `pd.DataFrame.melt`*</sub>

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'NAME': ['Anna', 'Mary', 'Paul'],
    2000: [5, 3, 2],
    2001: [4, 2, 3],
    2002: [3, 5, 4]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Unpivot df using melt
df = df.melt(id_vars=['NAME'], var_name='YEAR', value_name='SCORE')

print(df)
```

gives:

```
   NAME  YEAR  SCORE
0  Anna  2002      3
1  Mary  2001      2
2  Paul  2000      2
3  Paul  2001      3
4  Mary  2002      5
5  Anna  2001      4
6  Anna  2000      5
7  Mary  2000      3
8  Paul  2002      4
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually miraculously beat the answers to it, learned about melt, solved my issue and came back to close this haha.